# ImportError while importing a python package into a python module

Tags: python, eclipse, importerror

I create a python package namely ***package_demo*** and it has three python module ***init*.py**, **employee.py** and **manager.py**.

**employee.py:-**

```
def topSalary_employee(salary_list):
    return max(salary_list);

def leastSalary_employee(salary_list):
    return min(salary_list);

def avarageSalary_employee(salary_list):
    summation=0;
    for salary in salary_list:
        summation+=salary;
    return summation;
```

**manager.py:-**

```
def topSalary_manager(salary_list):
    return max(salary_list);

def leastSalary_manager(salary_list):
    return min(salary_list);

def avarageSalary_manager(salary_list):
    summation=0;
    for salary in salary_list:
        summation+=salary;
    return summation;
```

***init*.py:-**

```
from manager import*;
from employee import*;
```

Now I want to access all function of the **manager.py** and **employee.py** into another python module namely **AAA.py** which is resided outside the package ***package_demo***.Here is the code for AAA.py

**AAA.py:-**

```
import package_demo

employee_salary_list = [12000,23000,18000,25000,8000,17000];
manager_salary_list = [32000,45000,28000,50000,38000,44000];

print("\t...Manager Salary Details...");
print("Highest salary of Manager : ",package_demo.topSalary_employee(manager_salary_list));
print("Lowest salary of Manager : ",package_demo.leastSalary_manager(manager_salary_list));
print("Average salary of Manager : ",package_demo.avarageSalary_manager(manager_salary_list));

print("\t...Employee Salary Details...");
print("Highest salary of Employee : ",package_demo.topSalary_employee(employee_salary_list));
print("Lowest salary of Employee : ",package_demo.leastSalary_employee(employee_salary_list));
print("Average salary of Employee : ",package_demo.avarageSalary_employee(employee_salary_list));
```

But when I run AAA.py program,it will show some error likes below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Document\Files\Coding\Java Eclipse\Python Project\First Project\src\AAA.py", line 1, in <module>
    import package_demo
  File "F:\Document\Files\Coding\Java Eclipse\Python Project\First Project\src\package_demo\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from manager import*;
ImportError: No module named 'manager'
```

Comment: try `import manager.py`

Comment: It's not run after doing `import manager.py`.

Comment: Your code shows several newcomer mistakes. Did you have the time to go trough a Python tutorial? It might be very helpful.

Comment: @Morb: No, that will definitely not work. That's asking for a module named `py` in a package named `manager`.

Comment: oops, I wanted to say `from manager.py import *`

Comment: I've already used import something.py and it worked, or my memory is damaged

Comment: @Morb: If you happen to have a file named `manager/py.py` (and, for older versions of Python, also `manager/__init__.py`) then that will work. But it will never find something named `manager.py`. (Unless you write your own module finder and hook it into the import system…)

Comment: I tried again and yes, it doesn't work, sorry. I'll remember better next time

Comment: As a side note: `from .submodule import *` is a common practice with packages, but if things get complicated enough that you have multiple modules and you're editing them separately, it can lead to confusion. You may want to look through some stdlib and third-party modules to see how they handle this by creating an `__all__` in each module, and then an `__all__` in the `__init__.py` that merges them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All imports are evaluated from the directory you start Python in, so when init.py is trying to import manager Python will try to look from the directory you're currently in and not from the directory where init.py resides.

You wan to either use relative imports or convert your import to an absolute import:

Relative:

```
from .manager import*;
from .employee import*;
```

Absolute:

```
from package_demo.manager import*;
from package_demo.employee import*;
```

Comment: Well, not just the directory you start Python in, also all of the standard locations on `sys.path`. But otherwise, better explanation than mine, and faster too. :)